# Tried installing new graphics card and motherboard for pc, the pc turns on but the display doesn't seem to work

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building

I was trying to install a new graphics card for my pc (AMD Radeon 6750 XT).

I got it to the point where my PC turns on and I can see the graphics card is on by the fact that it's lit on the side. However, my monitor begs to differ as it does not seem to detect the display port cord hooked directly from the card into the it.

I saw some people saying that it could be because of a driver needing to be updated and that I should use an HDMI port to try and get into it and update the graphics card drivers, so I tried that and it wouldn't display anything with the HDMI either.

Does anyone have any advice for how to troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: Try the old graphics card. If it's the same, then the problem is either with the motherboard or with your mounting of it.

Comment: @harrymc I did try the old graphics card and it didn't work. But I can't imagine what the issue would be with the motherboard, it's also brand new because I tried it with a different motherboard and it didn't work so I changed to this motherboard. And I believe there shouldn't be any issues with the mounting, I've checked and re-checked.

Comment: This is already two motherboards that didn't work. It might be time for getting professional help.

Comment: @harrymc that sounds good, thank you for the help!